# Does Route 53 have a minimum TTL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Does Amazon Route 53 have a minimum TTL?

Comment: [AWS Route53 — Cheat Sheet(In 2 Minutes) | by Gaurav Gupta | Medium](https://gauravguptacloud.medium.com/aws-route53-cheat-sheet-in-2-minutes-ada9b7f0fcb) says it is 60 seconds.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That appears to be incorrect. I set a TTL of `1` without issues. The max TTL listed there is also incorrect.

Comment: In my experience, many client DNS resolvers will ignore short TTLs (less than 60 seconds, a few 5 seconds). @ceejayoz answer is correct but for a real-world answer, your question needs more details on how the TTL will be used. Setting the TTL to one second does no good if the clients refuse to honor it. The TTL is a suggestion and not a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm able to set a record to a one second TTL.

The interface states:

> Recommended values: 60 to 172800 (two days)

but no limits appear to be enforced; that said, remember that Route53 incurs a small per-query cost, so a very low TTL on a frequently requested record may wind up getting pricey.